# SELECT em 3 tabelas do banco com especificações

Tags: mysql, sql

Eu tenho três tabelas no banco, uma de empresas, outra de funcionários e outra de guias. Eu estou tentando fazer um SELECT que traga todas as empresas que tenha algum funcionário ligada a ela (existe a chave estrangeira na tabela), e que NÃO TENHA a guia HOLERITE na tabela "guias" relacionada a essa empresa.

```
 Tabela empresas
+--------+------+
| id     | nome |
+----------+----+
| 1      | abc  |
| 2      | hjk  |
| 3      | qwer |
| 4      | tyui |
| 5      | dfg  |
+--------+------+

 Tabela funcionários
+--------+------+-------------+
| id     | nome | empresas_id |
+----------+----+-------------+
| 1      | abc  |5            |
| 2      | hjk  |4            |
| 3      | qwer |3            |
| 4      | tyui |2            |
| 5      | dfg  |1            |
+--------+------+-------------+


     Tabela guias
+--------+----------+-------------+
| id     | tipo     | empresas_id |
+----------+--------+-------------+
| 1      | FGTS     |5            |
| 2      | INSS     |4            |
| 3      | HOLERITE |3            |
| 4      | INSS     |2            |
| 5      | FGTS     |1            |
+--------+----------+-------------+
```

O SELECT que eu estou fazendo é o seguinte:

```
SELECT
   emp.id, emp.nome_empresa
FROM
   empresas as emp
LEFT JOIN
   funcionarios as f
ON 
   f.empresas_id = emp.id
LEFT JOIN
   guias as g
ON 
   g.empresas_id = emp.id
WHERE
   f.empresas_id = emp.id
AND 
   g.tipo <> 'HOLERITE';
```

Porem está trazendo mesmo as empresas que tem a guia com o tipo HOLERITE.

Obs: Uma mesma empresa pode ter vários tipos registrados na tabela, mas preciso daquelas que não tem a guia HOLERITE registrada.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Tente:

```
SELECT emp.id, emp.nome_empresa
FROM empresas as emp JOIN funcionarios as f
ON f.empresas_id = emp.id
WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELETC * FROM guias as g WHERE g.empresas_id = emp.id 
    AND g.tipo = 'HOLERITE');
```

Pegue todas as empresas que tem algum funcionário e para a qual não exista a guia HOLERITE.